# Android: Accessing user login data from random fragments/activities

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm in the process of developing an app and I'm trying (and failing) to pass data between a chain of activities and fragments. As it stands, I have login/signup activities which work perfectly and save the user's credentials on an online MySqli database, and when a user logs in some of the credentials are passed to the main activity, which contains a container which displays fragments.

I've had no trouble passing data from this main activity to one of its fragments using a bundle, however, I now have a few subpages linking from a profile fragment that are accessed in this order: MainScreen - ProfileFragment - EditProfileFragment - ChangeUserName (a pop-up activity). The EditProfile frag also has a changeUserPicture button, but it'll use the same methods as the name change.

I need to pass the user's credentials from MainScreen to the ChangeUserName activity. I've tried using a chain of bundles that pass the strings when the activities/fragments are created but that didn't work properly.

I'm trying to use an interface to pass this data but I can't work out how to do it properly, any help on this will be greatly appreciated!

The code for the relevant activities and fragments is below:

MainScreen:

```
public class MainScreen extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageButton homeButton, searchButton, messageButton, contactsButton;
ImageView Luna;
ConstraintLayout homeView, searchView, lunaView, inboxView, contactsView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    final ImageButton homeButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bottom_home);
    final ImageButton searchButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bottom_search);
    final ImageView Luna = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_luna);
    final ImageButton messageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bottom_messages);
    final ImageButton contactsButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bottom_contacts);

    final ConstraintLayout homeView = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_section);
    final ConstraintLayout searchView = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.search_section);
    final ConstraintLayout lunaView = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.luna_section);
    final ConstraintLayout inboxView = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.inbox_section);
    final ConstraintLayout contactsView = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.contacts_section);

    final ImageButton profileButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profile_button);

    final TextView titleBarText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleText);

    homeView.setOnClickListener(this);
    searchView.setOnClickListener(this);
    lunaView.setOnClickListener(this);
    inboxView.setOnClickListener(this);
    contactsView.setOnClickListener(this);

    if (findViewById(R.id.container) != null) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        HomeFragment firstFragment = new HomeFragment();
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, firstFragment)
                .commit();
        titleBarText.setText("Home");

    }


    /*  This is the old toolbar button code. Keep just in case

    homeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment());
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });

    */
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final Integer user_id = intent.getIntExtra("user_id", 0);
    final String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    final String email = intent.getStringExtra("email");

    profileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Fragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();

            Bundle profileBundle = new Bundle();
            profileBundle.putInt("idKey", user_id);
            profileBundle.putString("nameKey", name);
            profileBundle.putString("emailKey", email);

            profileFragment.setArguments(profileBundle);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, profileFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.home_section:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();

            break;
        case R.id.search_section:
            fragment = new SearchFragment();

            break;
        case R.id.luna_section:
            fragment = new LunaFragment();

            break;
        case R.id.inbox_section:
            fragment = new MessageFragment();

             break;
        case R.id.contacts_section:
            fragment = new ContactsFragment();

            break;
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

ProfileFragment:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment{

MainScreen activity = (MainScreen) getActivity();

public ProfileFragment() {
}

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        final TextView userName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userFullName);
        final TextView userWorkplace = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.workplace);

        final Button workspaceButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.workspaceButton);
        final Button socialButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.socialspaceButton);
        final Button editProfileButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.editProfileButton);
        final Button preferencesButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.preferencesButton);
        final Button appSettingsButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.appSettingsButton);

        Bundle interfaceBundle = this.getArguments();


        if (interfaceBundle != null) {
            String nameBundle = getArguments().getString("nameKey"); //Get pass data with its key value
            userName.setText(nameBundle);
        } else {
            userName.setText("No Username Found");
        }

        editProfileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new EditProfileFragment());
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

    return view;
}





    @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    TextView title = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.titleText);
    title.setText("Profile");

    ImageButton icon = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profile_button);
    icon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.coolWhite));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ImageButton icon = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profile_button);
    icon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.slightGrey));
}
```

}

EditProfileFragment (just contains two buttons at the moment):

```
public class EditProfileFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, false);

    Button editName = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.changeUsernameButton);
    Button editPicture = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.changeProfilePictureButton);


    editName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), PopupNameChange.class));
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    TextView title = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.titleText);
    title.setText("Edit Profile");


    ImageButton icon = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profile_button);
    icon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.coolWhite));

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ImageButton icon = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profile_button);
    icon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.slightGrey));

}
```

}

PopupNameChange (the activity that opens to change the user's name. It pops up above the fragment in the centre of the screen, and doesn't override the previous views):

```
public class PopupNameChange extends Activity implements PracticeInterface{

String userName;

public void onFragmentInteraction(String userDataString) {
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pop_up_change_name);

    TextView userNameCurrent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCurrentName);

    //I want to pass the user's name to this activity to change the string of userNameCurrent
    userNameCurrent.setText(userName);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);


    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the fastest way to achive your goal will be to use `SharedPreferences`. Link to Google [site](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). Basically, when you get your data in Main Activity, instert that data to `SharedPreferences` like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("userName", userName);
editor.commit();
```

And in your `ChangeUserName` to get current user name:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String userName = sharedPref.getString("userName", defaultValue);
```

I shold also warn you. Do not hold sensitive data in `SharedPreferences`. It's easy for user with rooted phone to get data from `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: I'm getting a nullPointerException with this, and with a few other sharedPreference things such as getDefaultSharedPreferences. The data insertion within the Main Activity is in the onCreate method, whereas the data read code within the Name Change is not in the onCreate, will this make a difference?

Comment: Nevermind, I added getApplicationContext() rather than getActivity() and it allowed me to put it within the onCreate of the Name Change activity. Thanks for your help!!